# how do you revoke create table from a user on postgresql 9.4?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, postgresql-9.4

I'm trying to create a postgresql user that can select but can't create or drop, insert and so on on a database but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to prevent a user from creating its own tables.

What I've done so far:

```
create database test;
create role readonly;
alter role readonly with login;
alter role readonly with encrypted password 'test';
revoke all on schema public from public;
revoke all on schema public from readonly;
revoke all on database test from public;
revoke all on database test from readonly;
grant connect on database test to readonly;
```

Yet when I log in to the database as readonly I'm still able to create tables with impunity. What am I missing?

Comment: You are not connected to `test` when revoking schema permissions do it does not apply to that db.

Comment: Also note the user/role executing the revoke also needs to be the owner of the schema (so you can check that as well).  Refer to http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/709379.29248.qm@web37603.mail.mud.yahoo.com

Answer (score 8):

According to the documentation, what one needs for creating tables in a schema is `CREATE` on that schema.  This you think you revoked, but as you experience it didn't really happen - the only plausible explanation is that from [Daniel's comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115972/how-do-you-revoke-create-table-from-a-user-on-postgresql-9-4/115977#comment210691_115972): you are revoking access on the schemas of another database.

When you clear this up, you'll still need to grant/revoke the following:

- `GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO readonly;` to be able to access the objects in there
- `REVOKE ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public FROM public, readonly;`
- `GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO readonly;`
- and, if you plan to add new objects (tables) later, you have to set the default privileges, too.

Answer (score 8):

According to [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PRIV) you need to execute following query:

`REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;`

It revokes CREATE privilege on schema *public* from all users(except owner and superuser), so you have to grant it explicitly to users who need this privilege.

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for your contribution - however, I suggest taking a little look at the help pages https://dba.stackexchange.com/help to familiarise yourself with the site before posting answers. You may have noticed this question is pretty old, and has a contemporary up-voted answer already that's fairly comprehensive. I don't want to discourage you from posting answers at all (please do!) but take care to check that you're adding something new and useful - this is of particular necessity on older questions. Your time is much better spent on new or unanswered questions. Good luck and welcome!

Comment: I had a similar problem with PostgreSQL 10.5 recently and existing answer did not work for me neither on PostgreSQL 9.4 nor on newer version.

That's why I decided to post my own answer.